# How to access mouse coordinates in my directive (in Angular 2 for Dart)?

Tags: dart, angular2-directives, angular-dart

I'm using latest Angular 2 for Dart (version 3.1). In my custom directive implementation I can define [mouse events with annotations like this](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/attribute-directives#!#respond-to-user-initiated-events):

```
@HostListener('mouseenter')
void onMouseEnter() {
   do_something_here();
   //But how to access mouse coordinates here (MouseEvent object) ???
}
```

How can I access mouse coordinate on the object that I interacted with using mouse cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an `$event` argument to `@HostListener` annotation like this:

```
@HostListener('mouseenter', const [r'$event'])
void onMouseEnter(MouseEvent e) {
   //MouseEnter coordinates are following
   print("X = " + e.client.x.toString());
   print("Y = " + e.client.y.toString());
}
```